# Word for "best known function"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for *best known function*? I'm trying to say, for example, that lumber has been the best known function of timber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a single word:  **purpose**.

An items best known function is its purpose.

> The best purpose for harvesting timber is to make lumber.

In context, you might also use the term **derivative**.

> The most useful derivative of timber is lumber.

And, for completeness, consider **end-product**.

> Lumber is the typically desired end-product of processing timber.

Comment: Good, but that would create an ambiguity in my database.  Also, it's not specific enough, maybe.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I accept that criticism.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I think I have a better fit for you in my revision.

Comment: That is a really good one.  It may be better. I wish I could accept two answers.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I try not to tear down other answers in favor of my own.  But . . . read the comments section and the definition of byproduct.  It's not really the intended purpose of the process.  And, you are allowed to change which answer you accept, if you like.

Comment: What I'm thinking is basically: the most logical next step/'the best use'.  From an academic perspective, I just don't know how the intended purpose is important.  Essentially, in the database, I'm trying to use the definitive case (so, using "the").  So, let's look at the others: "the byproduct/derivative of a demon is a jackal"; "the byproduct/derivative of money is assets"; "the byproduct/derivative of placidity is intelligence"; "the byproduct/derivative of timber is lumber".  If derivative feels like a more natural collocation, how and why? (Should I reword my question or chance answers?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13718/discussion-between-david-m-and-wolfpack08)

Comment: @wolfpack'08 A byproduct is a side effect of the process.  An *end-product* is the expected outcome of the process.  And, the derivatives are all of the products of the process.  A byproduct of timber processing would be something like methyl alcohol. Not lumber.

Answer (score 4):

There's a good few options here:

> Lumber has been the **main use** for timber
>
> Lumber has been the **primary use** of timber
>
> Lumber has been the **most common use** of timber
>
> Lumber has been the **primary use** of timber
>
> Timber has **primarily been used** as lumber

Any of these are probably more than adequate for your example.

Comment: I was thinking of 'culmination' or something, you know?

Comment: Ideally a single word, though some of these are good

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence I think the term is **byproduct**.

Comment: Isn't byproduct anything that results from uses _other_ than the main function? In the case of timber, if we agree that lumber is the main use, firewood could be a byproduct?

Comment: @oerkelens  It is a tree, and then processed as timber.  Lumber and firewood would both be byproducts.

Comment: But a [byproduct](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+byproduct) is not the main thing created in a process, it is a _secondary_ product. To apply that word to the _main_ product seems strange.

Comment: @oerkelens - I hear you one this.  It is philosophical.  I am using the term loosely.  I think timber is the product of a tree and lumber is a byproduct of breaking down the tree.

Comment: Ok, that is about whether or not the OP's actual statement is correct or not. I agree that it is debatable, but since we are not on lumberjack.stackexchange.com, I was focusing on the language-part :P

Comment: That's good.  I may need a more general-purpose word, but that may work well.  It's very specific, so it might be perfect.  I need to cross-reference it.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best-purposed word for the database I'm working with. Thank you.